# In a lambda, does a by-value capture of a reference copy the underlying object?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

If a variable of reference type is captured in a lambda by value, is the referenced object copied or is it captured by reference?

Small sample with question:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
  int a;
};

void testFunc(const Test &test) {
  auto a = [=] {
    // is 'test' passed to closure object as a copy
    // or as a reference?
    return test.a;
  } ();
  std::cout << a;
}

int main() {
  Test test{1};
  testFunc(test);
}
```

Comment: Well, what about testing it? (You need to modify the object for that, which can be achieved by either trying with non-const reference or by making the variable `mutable`.)

Comment: Appears to be by [value](http://ideone.com/R0HclW).

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, testing is good, but it is always useful to see related Standard's sections and theoretically based answer (there are many such experts on SO).

Comment: Does knowing that references are not objects help here? Lambdas always capture objects, and they can do so by value or by reference.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

By value. Compilable example:

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    C(const C & source)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor called\n";
        i = source.i;
    }

    int i;
};

void test(C & c)
{
    c.i = 20;

    auto lambda = [=]() mutable {

        c.i = 55;
    };
    lambda();

    std::cout << c.i << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    C c;
    test(c);

    getchar();
}
```

Result:

```
Copy ctor called
20
```

I guess, that this paragraph of the C++ standard applies:

> ## 5.1.2 Lambda expressions
>
> (...)
> 14. An entity is captured by *copy* if it is implicitly captured and the *capture-default* is = or if it is explicitly
> captured with a capture that does not include an &. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed nonstatic
> data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified.
> The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a
> reference to an object, **or the referenced type otherwise**. [ *Note*: If the captured entity is a reference to a
> function, the corresponding data member is also a reference to a function. —*end note*]

That actually makes sense - if local variables are passed by value and parameter passed by reference "acts" as a local variable in function, why would it be passed by reference instead of value?

Comment: I think the important reason is that capturing by value is there so the variable is valid as long as the closure is. Which wouldn't work if the reference was not stripped.

Comment: The actual reason is that lambda capture types are *deduced*, and references are deduced as their referenced type. For more details see how [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) works.