# Why won't this lambda capture this variable with a deleted constructor by reference?

Tags: c++, lambda

My compiler, Visual Studio 19, says "Attempting to reference a deleted function":

```
class AClass 
{public:
    AClass(const AClass& other) = delete;
    AClass() {}
    AClass(AClass&& other) { }
    AClass& operator=(const AClass& other) = delete;
    AClass& operator=(AClass&& other) { return *this; }
    int member;
};


void main()
{
    AClass a;
    AClass& aRef = a;

    [=]() { return aRef.member; }; // "Attempting to reference a deleted function"

}
```

I assume it's trying to call the copy constructor, which is deleted, but I don't understand why as I'm trying to capture by reference by [=] value, meaning I don't copy the object AClass, I don't see how any copy is involved. My understanding is that the lambda looks something like this:

```
struct lambda {
    AClass& refToAClass; // <--- this is the captured object
    lambda(AClass& captureVariable) : refToAClass(captureVariable) {}
    int operator()() const
    {
        return refToAClass.member;
    }
};


void main()
{
      // AND I CAN CONSTRUCT THE LAMBDA, NO COPYING OF AClass INVOLVED
      AClass a;
      AClass& aRef = a;

      lambda lam(aRef); // WORKS FINE
}
```

How is a copy involved in this case? And how do I capture that reference?

Comment: If you want to capture by reference why not use `[&]()` instead of `[=]()` which is by value?

Comment: "capture by reference by [=] value" -> "capture a reference by [=] value" ? Is this a typo?

Comment: A reference is just another name for an object. Your lambda captures everything by value, and that includes that object, no matter how its named.

Comment: @CoryKramer Because that particular reference will be out of scope by the time the lambda function is called, I'm pretty sure. If I'm capturing the reference by reference, the reference will be invalid once the function exits, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*If I'm capturing the reference by reference, ...*". The lambda can be called while all the entities captured by reference are in scope, so if you can use `aRef` you can use the lambda.

Comment: Here is explained what's going on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676473/in-lambda-how-reference-is-being-captured-by-value
Because it cannot be copied, it will not work.

Comment: @cigien If AClass a; is still valid but the function exits and AClass aRef is not valid, won't capturing aRef by [&] reference then be an invalid reference? As opposed to capturing AClass c; by reference, which is still existing?

Comment: @Zebrafish There's no such thing as a reference to a reference. `int a = 0; int &b = a; auto c = b; auto &d = b;` In this example, `c` is an `int` with value `0` (it was copied), and both `b` and `d` are references to `a`.

Comment: "*If AClass a; is still valid but the function exi[s]ts and AClass aRef is not valid*". But `aRef` is in the same scope as `a` and refers to it. Doesn't even seem possible for one to be ok, but not the other.

Comment: @cigien I mean for example let's say AClass a; is a static variable somewhere in a class, or something like that. It will still be valid, and the aRef won't. I can't capture the aRef by [&] reference, can I?

Comment: I'd rather not answer that, as I'm not confident we'd be talking about the same thing. Instead, show a code snippet (as an edit to this question, or a new question), and we can reason about that.

Comment: No.  If you use [=], the members of the lambda get non-reference types declared.

Comment: `void main` should be `int main`.  The lambda should be `[&aRef=a]() { return aRef.member; };`.  The *"capture by reference by [=] value"* is not capture by reference.

Answer (score 3):

From [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10.2):

> **For each entity captured by copy**, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is** the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or **the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise**. A member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

[cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) worded it better:

> The type of each data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity, except if the entity has reference type (in that case, references to functions are captured as lvalue references to the referenced functions, and **references to objects are captured as copies of the referenced objects**).

Comment: "and references to objects are captures as copies of the referenced objects", how is having a lambda member AClass& aRef; copying the referenced object? Like even passed to the constructor, how is a copy involved?

Comment: The reference is stripped. If it weren't, things like capturing `*this` wouldn't work, as dereferencing a pointer yields an lvalue reference. Also, we'd have dangling reference issues with prvalues, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/eG6sWr

Comment: Think of a capture by value as using `auto`: if you did `auto v = aRef`, you'd have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps clarify what I think you're confused about:

```
template <typename T> void f(T arg) { }

int x = 10;
int& r = x;

auto y = r;     // y is int (copied value from reference)
f(r);           // T in f<T>() is deduced to int, arg in f() is int
```

In both cases if you want the result to be a reference, you must say so:

```
template <typename T> void f(T& arg) { }

int x = 10;
int& r = x;

auto& y = r;     // y is reference-to-int
f(r);            // T in f<T>() is int, arg in f is ref-to-int
```

Similarly, in your code:

```
AClass a;
AClass& aRef = a;

[=]() { return aRef.member; }; // "Attempting to reference a deleted function"
```

The captured aRef is an attempted COPY of the local variable from a reference to a different object.  using [=] says to copy by value, and it does *not* read this as "oh, the source is a reference, so I'm going to copy the reference by value and store the reference in a reference."  It actually says, "If the source type has reference qualifiers, ignore the and consider what's left.  You want to copy by value?  Ok, I'll copy an AClass into a new variable.  Oh wait... can't.  Sorry."

What you want is:

```
[&]() { return aRef.member; };
```

Or more specifically:

```
[&aRef]() { return aRef.member; };
```

That tells the captured type that it should be a reference.  The source type is not as important as the destination type in cases like this.

Comment: If aRef goes out of scope by the time the function is called, the reference inside the lambda is invalid, right?

Comment: @Zebrafish The reference in the lambda is a reference to the actual object, not to `aRef`.

Comment: Correct, dangling references are a problem to consider when doing by-reference captures. If the lambda outlives the referenced value, you have undefined behavior if you use it.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis That's OK, I thought capturing the reference by reference was different to capturing the object itself by reference. Apparently this isn't the case.