# Capturing the copy of a lambda that was owned by an already destructed object in a lambda leads to Segfault

Tags: c++, lambda, segmentation-fault

I have a class that essentially saves a `std::function<int(int)>` and allows for multiplication with others of it's type.
I do that by using lambdas:

```
class bla{
 public:
    bla(int n){
        func_ = [n](int a){return n;};
    }
    bla(std::function<int(int)> f){
        func_ = f;
    }
    bla operator*(const bla other)  const{
        return bla([=](int a){return this->func_(a)*other.func_(a);});
    }
    std::function<int(int)> func_;
};
```

Problem is: Even though I'm using the `[=]` capture, which according to this post:
[In a lambda, does a by-value capture of a reference copy the underlying object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676473/in-a-lambda-does-a-by-value-capture-of-a-reference-copy-the-underlying-object) should create a complete copy, I'm getting a Segfault if I multiply two of those objects and afterwards destroy at least one of them.

For example like this:

```
class blub{
 public:
    blub(std::initializer_list<bla> initlist){
        blas_ = initlist;
    }
    void multiply(){
        std::vector<bla> newblas;
        newblas.push_back(this->blas_[0]*this->blas_[1]);
        this->blas_ = newblas; //my old blas get deleted right here
    }
    
    std::vector<bla> blas_;
 };


int main()
{
     blub myblub = blub({bla(1), bla(2)});

     std::cout << myblub.blas_[0].func_(10); //this works

     myblub.multiply();

     std::cout << myblub.blas_[0].func_(10); //this doesn't

     return 0;
}
```

Which definitely looks like lambda is still using an internal reference to it's original function/lambda.
Is there some way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: capturing `this` by value does not make a copy of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@463035818_is_not_a_number is absolutely right.
`[=]` and `[this]` create copies, but only of the `this`-pointer.
It is though possible to capture the object pointed to by `this` with `[*this]`

Replacing `return bla([=](int a){return this->func_(a)*other.func_(a);});` with `return bla([*this, other](int a){return this->func_(a)*other.func_(a);});` fixes the issue on C++17 and C++20